# neovim not autoformatting as expected

Tags: typescript, neovim, vim-plugin

I'm using neovim, [vim-autoformat](https://github.com/vim-autoformat/vim-autoformat), and have a `.editorconfig` setup like so:

```
root = true

[*]
indent_style = spaces
indent_size = 2
```

This is what I expect:
[image]

however, when I run `:Autoformat`, this is what I get

[image]

I have confirmed that this is reading from .editorconfig, because when I change the tab length, I can see it visibly change from `:Autoformat`, however, it does appear that its inserting tabs, and it's also not indenting the way one would expect.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here, how should this be configured to deliver tabbing expectation to the first image?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the default formatter is most likely incorrectly set. I can force the formatter by running `:Autoformat typescript`, which gives me the indentation i'd expect.